# How do I get a dropped pin inside a MapView to save coordinates and present them as a String using SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, location, mapkit, coordinates, swiftui

I made a Form using SwiftUI, in which I have a section that allows a user to press on a button that takes them to a MapKit View. Once inside the map view, the user can press the "+" button to place a pin on a map. This takes them to the Edit View where they can enter text inside a TextField to label the pin (see screenshot below). I have been stuck here for the past few days attempting to save the pin's coordinates or even the user's input inside the TextField to return it as text (either as city, state or country) inside the Form.

[Form -> Map View -> Edit View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePuNF.jpg)

Here are some code snippets.

**1) From FormView:**

```
    import SwiftUI
    import MapKit

    struct FormView: View {
        @State private var selectedTitle = ""
        @State var meuf: Meuf
        @State private var meufs = [Meuf]()
        @State private var show = false
        @State private var singleIsPresented = false
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
        let newMeuf : Bool
        @EnvironmentObject var meufStorage : MeufStorage
        @State private  var showMap = false


        var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                Form{
                    //MARK: LOCATION
                    Section{
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: { self.showMap = true }) {
                                Image(systemName: "mappin.and.ellipse")
                            }
                            .sheet(isPresented: $showMap) {
                                LocationMap(showModal: self.$showMap)
                            }
                            Text("Pin your location")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                        }
                    }

                   // MARK: [ SAVE ENTRY ]
                    Section {
                        Button(action: {
                            if self.newMeuf {
                                self.saveData()
                                self.meufStorage.meufs.append(self.meuf)
                            } else {
                                for x in 0..<self.meufStorage.meufs.count {
                                    if self.meufStorage.meufs[x].id == self.meuf.id {
                                        self.meufStorage.meufs[x] = self.meuf
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }) {
                            HStack{
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Save")
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }.disabled(meuf.title.isEmpty)
                    }

                }.navigationBarTitle(Text(meuf.title))
            }
        }

        //Get file directory url
        func getFileDirectory() -> URL{
            let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            return paths[0]
        }

        //Load data from file directory
        func loadData(){
            let filename = getFileDirectory().appendingPathComponent("SavedPlaces")

            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: filename)
                meufs = try JSONDecoder().decode([Meuf].self, from: data)

            }catch{
                debugPrint(error)
            }
        }

        //Save data to file directory
        func saveData(){
            let filename = getFileDirectory().appendingPathComponent("SavedPlaces")
            let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self.meufs)
            do{
                try data?.write(to: filename, options: [.atomic , .completeFileProtection])
            }catch{
                debugPrint(error)
            }
        }

    }

    struct FormView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            FormView(meuf: Meuf(), newMeuf: true)
        }
    }
```

**2) From LocationMap:**

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct LocationMap: View {
    @State private var centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    @State private var locations = [CodableMKPointAnnotation]()
    @State private var selectedPlace: MKPointAnnotation?
    @State private var showingPlaceDetails = false
    @State private var showingEditScreen = false

    @Binding var showModal: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            MapView(centerCoordinate: $centerCoordinate, annotations: locations, selectedPlace: $selectedPlace, showingPlaceDetails: $showingPlaceDetails)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .opacity(0.3)
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action:{
                        let newLocation = CodableMKPointAnnotation()
                        newLocation.title = ""
                        newLocation.coordinate = self.centerCoordinate
                        self.locations.append(newLocation)

                        self.selectedPlace = newLocation
                        self.showingEditScreen = true
                    }){
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .shadow(radius: 0.7)
                    .padding([.trailing , .bottom])
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }.alert(isPresented: $showingPlaceDetails) {
            Alert(title: Text(selectedPlace?.title ?? "Unknown"), message: Text(selectedPlace?.subtitle ?? "Missing place information."), primaryButton: .default(Text("OK")), secondaryButton: .default(Text("Edit")) {
                self.showingEditScreen = true
                }
            )
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingEditScreen, onDismiss: savedData) {
            if self.selectedPlace != nil {
                EditView(placemark: self.selectedPlace!)
            }
        }


        .onAppear(perform: loadData)

    }
        func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
            let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            return paths[0]
        }

        func loadData() {
            let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Saved Places")

            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: filename)
                locations = try JSONDecoder().decode([CodableMKPointAnnotation].self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print("Unable to load saved data.")
            }
        }

        func savedData() {
            do {
                let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("SavedPlaces")
                let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self.locations)
                try data.write(to: filename, options: [.atomicWrite, .completeFileProtection])
            } catch {
                print("Unable to save data")
            }
        }

}
struct LocationMap_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LocationMap(showModal: .constant(true))
    }
}
```

**3) From MapView:**

```
import MapKit
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var annotations: [MKPointAnnotation]
    @Binding var selectedPlace: MKPointAnnotation?
    @Binding var showingPlaceDetails: Bool


    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
        if annotations.count != uiView.annotations.count{
            uiView.removeAnnotations(uiView.annotations)
            uiView.addAnnotations(annotations)
        }
    }

    ///Coordinator class for passing data
    class Coordinator: NSObject , MKMapViewDelegate{
        let parent: MapView

        init(_ parent: MapView){
            self.parent = parent
        }


        func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
            parent.centerCoordinate = mapView.centerCoordinate
        }

        //Gets called whenever the rightCalloutAccessory is tapped
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
            guard let placeMark = view.annotation as? MKPointAnnotation else {return}
            parent.selectedPlace = placeMark
            parent.showingPlaceDetails = true
        }

        //Customizes the way the marker looks
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            let identifier = "PlaceMark"
            var annotationview = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

            if annotationview == nil {
                annotationview = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

                annotationview?.canShowCallout = true

                annotationview?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            }else {
                annotationview?.annotation = annotation
            }

            return annotationview

        }


    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MapView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}




extension MKPointAnnotation {
    static var example: MKPointAnnotation {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = "Montreal"
        annotation.subtitle = "Home of French Canadians"
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 45.5, longitude: -73.58)
        return annotation
    }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView(centerCoordinate: .constant(MKPointAnnotation.example.coordinate), annotations: [MKPointAnnotation.example], selectedPlace: .constant(MKPointAnnotation.example), showingPlaceDetails: .constant(false))
    }
}
```

**4) From Edit View:**

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct EditView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var placemark: MKPointAnnotation

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Place name", text: $placemark.wrappedTitle)
                    TextField("Description", text: $placemark.wrappedSubtitle)
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Edit place")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Done") {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            })
        }

    }

}

struct EditView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EditView(placemark: MKPointAnnotation.example)
    }
}
```

**5) MKPointAnnotation Codable**

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class  CodableMKPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation , Codable {
    enum codingKeys: CodingKey {
        case title ,subtitle , longitude , latitude
    }
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws{
        super.init()

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: codingKeys.self)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        subtitle = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .subtitle)

        let latitude = try container.decode(CLLocationDegrees.self, forKey: .latitude)
        let longitude = try container.decode(CLLocationDegrees.self, forKey: .longitude)
        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: codingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
        try container.encode(subtitle, forKey: .subtitle)
        try container.encode(coordinate.latitude, forKey: .latitude)
        try container.encode(coordinate.longitude, forKey: .longitude)

    }
}
```

**6) MKPointAnnotation Object**

```
import MapKit

extension MKPointAnnotation: ObservableObject{
    public var wrappedTitle: String{
        get{
            self.title ?? "No Title"
        }
        set{
            self.title = newValue
        }
    }

    public var wrappedSubtitle: String{
        get{
            self.subtitle ?? "No information on this location"
        }
        set{
            self.subtitle = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

**7) Meuf & MeufStorage:**

```
import Foundation

struct Meuf: Identifiable, Encodable, Decodable {
    var id = UUID()
    var img = ""
    var title = ""
    var rating = 3.0
    var seen = false
    var seenDate = ""
}

class MeufStorage: ObservableObject {
    @Published var meufs = [Meuf]()
}
```

**8) Scene Delegate:**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let meufStorage = MeufStorage()
        let contentView = MeufList().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context).environmentObject(meufStorage)

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }


    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.saveContext()
    }


}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting all code which i can run on my side so will be faster to see

Comment: thet above once has so many missing } and other things are also missing please add a code which we can run and see the issue

Comment: Just added all the code. Let me know if you're able to run it now. And thank you.

Comment: Edit view missing
what is Meuf,MeufStorage??

Comment: 4 should have code relate to Edit view  but has LocationMap same as 2.

Comment: My bad, I copy pasted LocationMap into EditView by mistake. Just corrected it.

Comment: can you please also add what it these 2?
Meuf,MeufStorage

Comment: Also i will need func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)
code of this function from SceneDelegate

Comment: It's just to handle storage... But I've already deleted them. I just want to know how to convert coordinates or the pin's label text edited by the user into a String property that I can use to display somewhere else in the app.

Comment: Okey i was not able to run it properly so was not able to get to a solution will check by removing this storage code

Comment: It would have be nice if have got the runnable code at first go.

Comment: Just added them back - see edit. thanks!

Comment: Okey now i was able to see some ui. End goal is when you see the edit fields and press done you want the data from the text fields to the map screen??

Comment: Hey Mafishi i can see the data also properly on the annotation view and also when i say edit on the edit screen i see my data prefilled. What is the problem here again??

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tARygxr Map markers show annotations

Comment: see the screenshots here i think everything is working

Comment: yes that is fine. What I want to do is somehow grab the text data and display it inside of my form by replacing where it said "pin your location"

Comment: That you have to store it in somewhere and the fetch to show on ui

Comment: it's hard to communicate and explain here 
possible to connect via screen share??

Comment: if yes you can join this 
https://zoom.us/j/264265711?pwd=bUlWWERIMDg0NDZYN1g2NXFESW5kdz09

i will be online for some time on this if you join will be faster to solve

Comment: Hey buddy still there??

I managed to get it work

Comment: Awesome! I'll try and join again in a few mins if you're there. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I managed to get the solution.

Will add code only which is changed

```
// Made this a ObservableObject
class Meuf: Identifiable, Codable, ObservableObject {
var id = UUID()
var img = ""
var title = ""
var rating = 3.0
var seen = false
var seenDate = ""
var locations = [CodableMKPointAnnotation]() // We need this to keep the track of locations
}
```

**FormView**

```
struct FormView: View {
    @State private var selectedTitle = ""

    @ObservedObject var meufObject = Meuf() // This is new will help to keep track of the added locations

    @State private var meufs = [Meuf]() 
    @State private var show = false
    @State private var singleIsPresented = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var meufStorage : MeufStorage
    @State private  var showMap = false


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form {
                List {
                    // This will list the added locations now
                    ForEach(self.meufObject.locations, id: \.self) { location in
                        LocationView(location: location)
                    }
                }

                //MARK: LOCATION
                Section{
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: { self.showMap = true }) {
                            Image(systemName: "mappin.and.ellipse")
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showMap) {
                            LocationMap(meufObject: self.meufObject, showModal: self.$showMap)
                        }
                        Text("Pin your location")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                }

                // MARK: [ SAVE ENTRY ]
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        // Handle save action
                    }) {
                        HStack{
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Save")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    // Rest of your code stays same .......
}

// Added this new view to render the location view
struct LocationView: View {
    var location : CodableMKPointAnnotation
    var body: some View {
        Text(location.title ?? "title" )
    }
}
```

**LocationMap**

```
struct LocationMap: View {
    @ObservedObject var meufObject: Meuf // This is new will help to keep track of the added locations

    @State private var centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    @State private var locations = [CodableMKPointAnnotation]()
    @State private var selectedPlace: MKPointAnnotation?
    @State private var showingPlaceDetails = false
    @State private var showingEditScreen = false

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    @Binding var showModal: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            MapView(centerCoordinate: $centerCoordinate, annotations: locations, selectedPlace: $selectedPlace, showingPlaceDetails: $showingPlaceDetails)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .opacity(0.3)
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action:{
                        let newLocation = CodableMKPointAnnotation()
                        newLocation.title = ""
                        newLocation.coordinate = self.centerCoordinate
                        self.locations.append(newLocation)
                        self.meufObject.locations = self.locations // By doing this we will be able to pass it to main screen
                        self.selectedPlace = newLocation
                        self.showingEditScreen = true
                    }){
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .shadow(radius: 0.7)
                    .padding([.trailing , .bottom])
                    // Rest stays same as your implementation
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    // Rest stays same as your implementation
}
```